# JSNAPY: Is there a way to test on xpath node attributes

Tags: xpath, junos-automation, pyez

I am trying to determine how to test on the node attributes that junos occasionally uses. In this particular case, I want to find all BGP sessions that are down between 20w and 1y. The seconds value is contained in the node attribute, but I have not been able to figure out how to access it for the test.

I have tried various methods using the entire explicit xpath, all the way to what I have below in the code.

Here is the xpath I am trying to access (edited for brevity):

```
<rpc-reply xmlns:junos="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/18.2R3/junos">
    <bgp-information xmlns="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/18.2R3/junos-routing">
        <bgp-peer junos:style="terse" heading="Peer                     AS      InPkt     OutPkt    OutQ   Flaps Last Up/Dwn State|#Active/Received/Accepted/Damped...">
            <elapsed-time junos:seconds="263788">3d 1:16:28</elapsed-time>
        </bgp-peer>
    </bgp-information>
</rpc-reply>
```

```
test_bgp_summ:
  - rpc: get-bgp-summary-information
  - iterate:
      xpath: /bgp-information/bgp-peer
      id: ./peer-address
      tests:
        - in-range: //@junos:seconds, 12096000, 31449600
          err: ""
          info: 'Peer session <{{id_0}}> is likely stale'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the elapsed-time node in your test:

```
show_bgp_sum:
  - command: show bgp summary
  - iterate:
      xpath: '//bgp-information/bgp-peer'
      id: ./peer-address
      tests:
        - exists: elapsed-time/@seconds
          err: "elpased-time doesn't exist"
          info: "Elapsed-time is: <{{post['elapsed-time/@seconds']}}>"
```

and the output:

```
                   "passed": [
                        {
                            "actual_node_value": "1309804", 
                            "id": {
                                "./peer-address": "10.10.12.100"
                            }, 
                            "message": "Elapsed-time is: <1309804>", 
                            "post": {
                                "elapsed-time/@seconds": "1309804"
                            }, 
                            "pre": {
                                "elapsed-time/@seconds": "1309802"
                            }
                        },
```